# Golang как узнать текущее время

Tags: golang

Как узнать локальное время/мировое с помощью Golang, искал в интернете нашел что нужно создать функцию Now и записать как Time:

```
func Now() Time
```

Но мне нужно использовать как переменную, а не как функцию, как реализовать?

Answer (score 6):

```
import (
 "fmt"
 "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf(t.Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```